# I recently converted and i want to be able to pray 5 times a day, but i don’t know how to start?

Tags: salat, conversion

I recently converted and I want to be able to pray my 5 times a day, but I don’t know what to say or how to do it and it’s also difficult because I don’t speak Arabic although I am learning, I am just a beginner. I was wondering if anyone could help me in knowing what to say and how to get better at learning it. thank you.

Comment: Associate yourself with people that know how to pray and always asked from them

Comment: Find some videos about Salah and wudu, there's also apps that can help you. Take notes and follow that. Inshallah you would not need the notes anymore after some time.